# Merge two objects with different keys in chartjs bar

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have two jsons:

```
first: {
"a": 1,
"b": 9,
"c": 12,
"d": 5
}
```

and

```
second: {
"a": 7,
"e": 8,
"b": 11,
"f": 7
}
```

and i want to create chartjs bar that include both json (with two datasets).
The labels should be 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' and the "first" dataset's data will be: 1, 9, 12, 5, 0, 0. The "second" dataset's data will be: 7, 11, 0, 0, 8, 7.

My code right now:

```
var barChartData = {
    labels: Object.keys(first),
    datasets:[
        {
            label:'first',
            data: Object.values(first)
        },
        {
        label: 'second',
        data: Object.values(second)
        }]
};

window.myBar = new Chart(document.getElementById("barChart").getContext("2d"),
{
    type:'bar',
    data: barChartData
});
```

The problem is that i want the labels to be from the keys of both 'first' and 'second' jsons and not just from the 'first' and also that the values will be suitable to the keys.

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: please add the result as well - and what you have tried. worth a look: [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want both objects to have the same keys but with a value of zero when the keys aren't defined. There are several ways to do this. One option would be to make a list of the combined keys of both objects and just loop over them setting the object's value to 0 if the key doesn't exist:

```js
let first = {"a": 1,"b": 9,"c": 12,"d": 5  }  
  
let second = {"a": 7,"e": 8,"b": 11,"f": 7} 

Object.keys(Object.assign({}, first, second))    // get combined keys
.forEach(k => {
  if (!first.hasOwnProperty(k))  first[k] = 0;   // set 0 if key is not in object 
  if (!second.hasOwnProperty(k)) second[k] = 0;
})
console.log(first, second)
```